# Is there a way to find ALL permissions, attributes, etc. on a file from the command line?

Tags: permission

Migrated to a new machine, but due to some reasons I won't get into, I ended up copying a number of files over from a Time Machine backup directly (i.e. didn't "restore from time machine") to get them on to my new machine's disk. Everything seemed fine, but I realized that while I can *read* the files, I can't *write* to them unless I `sudo`.

While I've worked around the problem by just using a USB stick instead to transfer the files, I'm left curious why I have files which I can't write to unless I sudo.

For the record, I've observed:

- The standard `ls -l` UNIX permission view shows that my user/group has proper 'rwx' permissions on the file.
- From Finder "Get Info", it says that my user should have full Read/Write access.
- From the `xattr -l` view of the file, I don't see anything that would suggest it would stop me from writing to the file. At best, I've seen one in regards to a time machine metadata referencing when the file was backed up.

Is there something else I could look at? As I said, I got around the issue with a new copy, but I'm just curious what else macOS could be considering that would make these files on my SSD read-only.

Comment: Did you look at `man ls`?

Comment: Does `ls -l` show an `@` at the beginning of permissions?

Comment: @nohillside yes, and @Barmar yes.  But the `xattr` command I noted does the same thing as `ls -l@`.  Example xattr output: com.apple.timemachine.private.directorycompletiondate: 2023-09-14-233118,3,1013,376832,96,0,0,0

Comment: Extended attributes are less important than ACLs when diagnosing permission issues.

Comment: Can you post the complete Terminal output for a file? Are you actually the owner of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files copied directly from Time Machine usually come with some ACL (Access Control List) entries which may prevent deletion or overwriting.

- To see the ACLs defined for a file, use `ls -el FILE`.
- To manipulate them, use `chmod` with the appropriate options (details in `man chmod`).

Comment: This is what I was looking for; never dug into the chmod manipulation of ACLs.  Found that Time Machine put a " 0: group:everyone deny add_file,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,writeattr,writeextattr,chown" ACL on everything, so removing it with `chmod -a# 0` got rid of it!